# Ensure packet owner from connection is the authentic user

Tags: multiplayer, security, packet, hacks

In a multiplayer game, how can you be sure that the IP from a packet is the real IP? By spoofing I could send, for example, a "suicide packet" which tells the server that the owner of said packet wants to destroy its avatar when in reality I faked it.

Do games just give up on this aspect?

Comment: As far as I know the standard way to ensure authenticity is to use asymmetric encryption.